# stored Procedure usage in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, visual-studio-2010, stored-procedures

I am using `StoredProcedure` in sqlserver 2005.

**Stored Procedure:**

```
create proc useGetASP @PartyCode nvarchar(50)
as
select * 
from partyRegister 
where PartyCode=@PartyCode
Go
```

I was trying to execute it with asp.net visual studio 2010.

By researching for code i came to know i should use

```
 cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
```

But unfortunatly CommandType.StoredProcedure is not there , its not working.

Hence i used:

```
cmd.CommandType = SqlDataSourceCommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

But this is also not working. It shows me red line below it [As comes when we type something invalid].
As a tooltip it shows me error as: `CommandType does not exists in current context`

**My Full Code:**

```
con.Open();
cmd = new SqlCommand("useGetASP",con);
//cmd.CommandType =CommandType./*Not Working*/
cmd.CommandType = SqlDataSourceCommandType.StoredProcedure;/*Also Not Working*/
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PartyCode","0L036");
```

What is my mistake?

What command should i use for implementing stored procedure?

Please Help Me.

Comment: What error you are getting ??

Comment: CommandType does not exists in current context

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try like this:

```
System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure
```

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.commandtype.aspx

Answer (score 3):

First use this `namespace`

```
using System.Data;
```

Then you should be able to use:

```
CommandType.StoredProcedure
```

Answer (score 2):

Need to use like this

```
System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure
```

Also make it sure that Reference to System.Data is needed.

Answer (score 2):

try using the namespace `using System.Data;`

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing the blow line

```
using System.Data;
```

You need to use this namesapce for "SqlDataSourceCommandType.StoredProcedure" .

Comment: Yeah it's my mistake. Thanks for your response.